# Java Applet Can not be display on local style

Tags: java, applet

I am learning Java Applet now, I created following Java Applet code

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class AppletDemo1 extends Applet{
    public void mai(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("Hello World Wide Web", 60, 60);
    }
}
```

Using Eclipse, debug is passed.

Then I created a HTML files as below,

```
<Applet
CODE = "AppletDemo1.class"
WIDTH = 300 HEIGHT = 150>
</APPLET>
```

When I double click this HTML file or open it from Firefox or MS IE "file", all does not work. Page just shows blank and nothing shown

I change to the following HTML

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div >
<APPLET CODE="AppletDemo1.class" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="500">
</APPLET>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Then open html file under FireFox, system running, but page is stucking there, whole page is blank, other application becomes slow, I am waiting couple minutes, it seems to be running but no any output

Can anybody tell me what's fail reason?
Thanks a lot

Tony

Comment: Can you show html with applet?  Also check if Java is installed in browser.  Try going to java.com and check if it works.  Java is often disabled in browser.

Comment: Thanks, I just added source code in above. It's pretty simple, just for an exercise, I can see www.java.com

Answer (score 0):

First of all keep compile your class using `javac AppletDemo1.java` and keep the generate `AppletDemo1.class` and the html file in the same folder

Try to give background-color to the body of the html file so that you can see the applet is running
Then if you want to run the applet just open command prompt and type

```
appletviewer yourHtmlFileName.html
```

it will pop up your applet

or if you want to display it in a browser just right-click on the html file and open it with Internet Explorer, it will display you the applet.

One more thing Add some text between the applet tags so that you can know its running if it displays the text in the browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that didnt work. I have tried to switch PC from Win XP(32bit) to Vista(32bit) then to Win7(64bit), all doesn't work, also tested IE, FireFow, and Chrome, Also doesn't work

Comment: What's the condition of Windows system for run Applet??? I just copied the text book's a very simple sample for exercising Applet, but it is so hard to pass. To the Windows XP, 32bits, what environment is necessary to run Java applet? Java is really too hard to using, almost a junk.....

Comment: I have put the AppletDemo1.class file with html file in the same folder, I used Eclipse to generated the class file and saved it before running html file, it's really hard to think about what the reason is. Is the Java Applet a real product???

Comment: thats impossible that should work fine btw what error you are getting

Comment: start - >control panel -> java(if unable to find type java in the search field of control panel) -> Then click on it a menu pops up go to security tab -> then make the security label to medium and ok.

Answer (score 0):

How do you think your method `public void mai(Graphics g)` will get called?.

Please read the Java tutorial on applets (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/).

See the following simple example:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

//No need to extend JApplet, since we don't add any components;
//we just paint.
public class Simple extends Applet {

    StringBuffer buffer;

    public void init() {
        buffer = new StringBuffer();
        addItem("initializing... ");
    }

    public void start() {
        addItem("starting... ");
    }

    public void stop() {
        addItem("stopping... ");
    }

    public void destroy() {
        addItem("preparing for unloading...");
    }

    private void addItem(String newWord) {
        System.out.println(newWord);
        buffer.append(newWord);
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    //Draw a Rectangle around the applet's display area.
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 
           getWidth() - 1,
           getHeight() - 1);

    //Draw the current string inside the rectangle.
        g.drawString(buffer.toString(), 5, 15);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. I modified the html file as below,              
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    Hello!
    <div >
    <APPLET CODE=".\AppletDemo1.class" WIDTH="500" HEIGHT="500">
    </APPLET>
    </div>
     Hello Again Again!
    </BODY>
    </HTML>

Comment: After running html file, I can see two rows message being shown, in here are "Hello" and "He;;o again, again", but still can not see Applet part, it shows "Application error" and unable to fine applet file(ApppletDemo1.class), I copy/paste the error messages are as below, I used MS IE browser        Java Plug-in 1.6.0_21
Using JRE version 1.6.0_21-b07 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Documents and Settings\evergreen

Comment: ----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect

Comment: ----------------------------------------------------


load: class .\AppletDemo1.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ..AppletDemo1.class
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 9 more
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ..AppletDemo1.class

Comment: Could anybody tell me, why system unable to find applet file??? in here it is "AppletDemo1.class", I have put it in the same folder with html file, also imply the applet file's detail path in the html file

Comment: `APPLET CODE=".\AppletDemo1.class"` should be `APPLET CODE="AppletDemo1.class"` ie no ".\"